# How glimpse persists debugging information?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, load-balancing, glimpse, web-farm

How does [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) persist collected data? Is it all saved in memory? Is there a way to persist the data in a database?

I ask this because if I have a website installed on multiple machines (load balancing) can I use glimpse for debugging, or is the data collected from one server not accessible from other servers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`IPersistenceStore`](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/739afdba40e61ea31b42e6d0ddfbeed8f9c561be/source/Glimpse.Core/Framework/IPersistenceStore.cs) is the interface to implement.

Glimpse ships out of the box with an in memory store called [`ApplicationPersistenceStore`](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/739afdba40e61ea31b42e6d0ddfbeed8f9c561be/source/Glimpse.Core/Framework/ApplicationPersistenceStore.cs), but your implementation could write the data to a database, filesystem, distributed cache - whatever meets your needs.

To wire your implementation into Glimpse, you'll need to create an [`IServiceLocator`](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/739afdba40e61ea31b42e6d0ddfbeed8f9c561be/source/Glimpse.Core/Framework/IServiceLocator.cs) and configure Glimpse to use it via the `serviceLocatorType` attribute on the `glimpse` node in `web.config`.

If you'd like to see a sample `IServiceLocator` implementation, you can take a look at [`AspNetServiceLocator`](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/739afdba40e61ea31b42e6d0ddfbeed8f9c561be/source/Glimpse.AspNet/AspNetServiceLocator.cs).

Answer (score 3):

From looking at the [History tab](http://getglimpse.com/Help/History-Tab) page I suspect the documentation has yet to be written, it currently says this:

> **Persistense Store**
>
> **TODO:** Link to example of how to update `IPersistenseStore`.

I've looked through the code and cannot find a `IPersistenseStore` interface. But I can find the [`IDataStore`](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/739afdba40e61ea31b42e6d0ddfbeed8f9c561be/source/Glimpse.Core/Extensibility/IDataStore.cs) interface which is where I suggest you start looking.

There currently appears to be two implementations of the interface, the [`DictionaryDataStoreAdapter`](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/739afdba40e61ea31b42e6d0ddfbeed8f9c561be/source/Glimpse.Core/Extensibility/DictionaryDataStoreAdapter.cs) class and the [`HttpApplicationStateBaseDataStoreAdapter`](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/739afdba40e61ea31b42e6d0ddfbeed8f9c561be/source/Glimpse.AspNet/HttpApplicationStateBaseDataStoreAdapter.cs) class.

---

**Update**

There is an [`IPersistenceStore`](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/739afdba40e61ea31b42e6d0ddfbeed8f9c561be/source/Glimpse.Core/Framework/IPersistenceStore.cs) interface which is implemented by the [`ApplicationPersistenceStore`](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/739afdba40e61ea31b42e6d0ddfbeed8f9c561be/source/Glimpse.Core/Framework/ApplicationPersistenceStore.cs) class. Though this class seems to defer to a [`IDataStore`](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/739afdba40e61ea31b42e6d0ddfbeed8f9c561be/source/Glimpse.Core/Extensibility/IDataStore.cs), so that's probably still the place to look to implement a custom solution.

Comment: Great answer James! Please feel free to update the wiki documentation at any time or provide us any feedback you may have.

Comment: @nikmd23 I've just updated the documentation to correct interface spelling mistake, as that's what originally threw me. I'm considering writing a store using Azure's In-Memory distributed caching, if I do I'll open source it and publish a nuget package.

Comment: Sounds great! Let me know if you need any help.