# Is it possible to save to Session when persisting information in Glimpse?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, glimpse

I've implemented IPersistenceStore and IServiceLocator in my MVC web site as stated in below link. I'm wondering if it's possible to save the information to the session? HttpContext.Current.Session seems to be null when I'm trying to reach it in the save methods in PersistenceStore.

[How glimpse persists debugging information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198195/how-glimpse-persists-debugging-information/16217996#16217996?newreg=44f35044ae2d4eb68ee7a2b31de01422)

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported by Glimpse and ASP.NET.

Glimpse saves request information during the [`EndRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.endrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) event, which happens after the [`PostReleaseRequestState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postreleaserequeststate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - which is when `Session` state is written back to the session store.