# Persisting Dashboard Info for Glimpse for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, logging, glimpse, diagnostics

How do I persist [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) (for MVC4) information for historical purposes? For example, I would like to store specific dashboard data items (e.g., time on the wire) a database, per request, so as to create a chart based on that. I have searched all over the docs and forums for something like this, but I have not found anything really useful for setting up this use case.

This question may be related to [How glimpse persists debugging information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198195/how-glimpse-persists-debugging-information). It suggests implementing [IDataStore](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/739afdba40e61ea31b42e6d0ddfbeed8f9c561be/source/Glimpse.Core/Extensibility/IDataStore.cs)
However, if go down this route, how do I actually reference my interface implementation so my Glimpse installation will use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only interested in persisting the data and getting it out independently (for your dashboard) that should be fairly easy. You will will probably want to inherit from [`ApplicationPersistenceStore`](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Core/Framework/ApplicationPersistenceStore.cs) (which implements [`IPersistenceStore`](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Core/Framework/IPersistenceStore.cs)) so that you get the out of the box behavior of the default `PersistenceStore` and just save off to your store before calling `base.Seve(...)`.

In order to register the you will want to take a look at whats going on [here](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/f8aeb1446ce3e00c0e0c1f8a7f2bb3b508f5825c/source/Glimpse.Core/Framework/Factory.cs#L242-L251). You will see that we look to the `UserServiceLocator` (which is a [`IServiceLocator`](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Core/Framework/IServiceLocator.cs)) to see if you want to customize whats going on. To register your service locator, you can do this off the `Glimpse` config section. [Here](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/f8aeb1446ce3e00c0e0c1f8a7f2bb3b508f5825c/source/Glimpse.Test.Core/App.config#L6) is an example of how to do it:

```
  <glimpse serviceLocatorType="Glimpse.Test.Core.TestDoubles.DummyServiceLocator, Glimpse.Test.Core" ...>
```

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Thanks, but there is nothing to override on ApplicationPersistenceStore; How to I extend it's it's Save() method? I think it is better to implement IPersistenceStore using an internal ApplicationPersistenceStore. Then the ApplicationPersistenceStore also requires an IDataStore upon instantation, so I guess I will have to provide an implementation of that as well.

Comment: Got it working, thanks! But I wonder how to extract the display view timings data (such as total query, view, action/controller, and wire time) from the GlimpseRequest object passed to the Save() method of the my custom  IPersistenceStore. Also, how do I enable such logging (but without displaying the Glimpse tabs to users) in production mode?

Comment: Look at the `DisplayData` property of the `GlimpseRequest` object passed into the the `Save(...)` method. I can't remember which key exactly it is but you should be able to set a break point and have a look for the data you need.